# Devexpress DataGrid contextmenu disappear

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid, devexpress

I have a strange problem with DataGrid context menu. I load item details from server after click on a item in datagrid. While loading the details the application shows a waitscreen:

```
private void gridViewOrders_MouseDown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     GridView gv = sender as GridView;

     if (gv != null)
     {
          ShowWaitScreen (message);

          GridHitInfo ghi = gv.CalcHitInfo (e.Location);
          ...      
          CloseWaitScreen ( );      
     }
}
```

When the user click the right mouse button, it should shows a context menu:

```
 private void gridViewOrders_PopupMenuShowing (object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.MenuType == GridMenuType.Row)
      {
           DXMenuItem item = new DXMenuItem ("Delete", OnBtnDeleteOrder_Click);
           e.Menu.Items.Add (item);
      }
 }
```

But the menu disappear at once. When I remove the waitscreen, the context menu is shown and the user can select the "Delete" menuitem. Any hints, how I can fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I'd imagine you don't want to show the Wait Screen when they right click, only left click, correct? `if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) return;`

Comment: That is not a bad idea, I will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good solution for my problem is to do the following:

```
 private void gridViewOrders_MouseDown (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      GridView gv = sender as GridView;

      if (gv != null)
      {
           if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
           {
                ShowWaitScreen (message);
                ...
                CloseWaitScreen ( )
           }
       }
 }
```

Thanks to the DevExpress team for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

I dont really thisnk you need to handle anything in MouseDown event.

This code works for GridView:

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    GridView view = sender as GridView;

    if (e.MenuType == DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMenuType.Row)
    {
        int rowHandle = e.HitInfo.RowHandle;
        e.Menu.Items.Clear();

        DXMenuItem zaznaczItem = new DXMenuItem("Zaznacz wszystkie", new EventHandler(zaznacz_Click));
        DXMenuItem odznaczItem = new DXMenuItem("Odznacz wszystkie", new EventHandler(odznacz_Click));
        e.Menu.Items.Add(zaznaczItem);
        e.Menu.Items.Add(odznaczItem);
    }
}

void zaznacz_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (DataRow dr in (gcKontrahent.DataSource as DataTable).Rows)
     {
         dr["checkbox"] = true;
     }
}
```

Handler **zaznacz_Click** is just example of handler for selected menu item. **odznacz_Click** is similar so I didnt post it. I dont have example for DataGrid so excuise me if it's not good solution. Just take it as example for acomplishing context menu handling in GridView.